# Sql querying a matrix

Tags: ms-access, matrix

I want to query the following table  in access

```
Productid   LowEnd  MidRange    HighEnd

1           10%     15%         25%

2           13%     18%         28%

3           14%     19%         30%
```

based on both the Productid and the CLass (Lowend,midrange,Highend) is there anyway to do it without manually  creating  a newtable?, I can do it easily by writing an excel macro to make a new table. I have used the crosstab to make tables like these.. can we undo them?

EDIT:
lets say the table name above is 'matrix' 
The query I want to be able to do is SELECT * FROM matrix WHERE ((matrix.Productid = 1) and (column = 'LowEnd')) . I know column = lowend is not valid in sql so... I guess I'll have to use the Union of multiple queries which have the where caluse to identify the correct coulmn.

Comment: Could you show us the table definitions (create statements) so we can see where this data comes from?

Comment: I copied it from an excel file into an access table.. no create statement was used.

Comment: Could you provide an example of a query that you can't currently create against this schema?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I guess I'll have to use the Union of
>   multiple queries which have the where
>   cause to identify the correct column.

I think you provided your own answer. The restriction is all the rows must be of the same data type or at least data types implicitly convertibles each others.

```
SELECT Productid, LowEnd AS Value
UNION
SELECT Productid, MidRange AS Value
UNION
SELECT Productid, HighEnd AS Value
```

Comment: hmm I wonder if SQL server and others have the option of choosing the column based on the result of a previous query??